# Android Studio: How to parse a JSON Object from Inside of a JSON Array?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to parse the following JSON data into a recycler view. In particular, I want to parse the address object to display the locationName, line1, city, state and zip, but I cant get the parsing method right.

```
   {
 "pollingLocations": [
  {
   "address": {
    "locationName": "LITTLE LEAGUE HEADQUARTERS",
    "line1": "6707 LITTLE LEAGUE DR",
    "city": "SAN BERNARDINO",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": "92407"
   },
   "notes": "",
   "pollingHours": "07:00-20:00",
   "sources": [
    {
     "name": "Voting Information Project",
     "official": true
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

My issue is finding the address object. With the current code, I get a logcat error that says No value for locationName. I think this is because I first need to specify the address object to iterate through, but how do I do this? This is the current implementation that I have right now.

```
//fetch
private void getData() {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("pollingLocations");
                for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject addressObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    for (int x = 0; x < addressObject.length(); x++){
                        VotingLoc votingLoc = new VotingLoc(addressObject.getString("locationName"),
                                addressObject.getString("line1"),
                                addressObject.getString("city"),
                                addressObject.getString("state"),
                                addressObject.getString("zip"),
                                addressObject.getString("pollingHours"));
                        votingList.add(votingLoc);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Locat Error: 
[image]

Is there an easier way of doing this? I believe the code for my rvadapter class and is correct and the error is in this method, but If you want to see any other code, let me know.

Comment: You are missing node `address`

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, but when I create a jsonObject for address the logcat error then says no value for address. Can you bhe a little more specific on how you would implement this?

Comment: Do i need a nested for loop in the scenario? How can I do it without one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By getting first node in array you have obtained `address` node so no need to run `loop` there, `address` object is not an array you can get values directly. Try something like this:

```
        JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("pollingLocations");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
           String locationName = jsonObject.getJSONObject("address")
                   .getString("locationName");
           Log.d("locationName", locationName);
            JSONArray sourcesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sources");

          // run loop to get values from this array
          for (int j = 0; j < sourcesArray.length(); j++){
                JSONObject source = sourcesArray.getJSONObject(j);
                String name = source.getString("name");
            }
        }
```

Comment: This was the first solution I had in mind, but whenever I try to create the JSONObject and pass "address" as a parameter I get a syntax error. I can only pass an integer as an index of the array and not a string.

Comment: I can pass index i from the for loop but it wont let me pass a string

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be using a json parser like gson (https://github.com/google/gson) or jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). This may be a bit overhead if your only goal is to show these few values, as you must create some java classes, you may only need for parsing.